# TestNG Listeners not running if they are in dependency

Tags: testng, maven-3

I have a set of listeners defined in Project A as part of its source including tests for those annotations.

When I use Project A as a project dependency on Project B the annotations are not called at all even when I have to include them in the test classes when using them and everything compiles.

Any idea how to make this work?

See sample project [here](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/2101).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TestNG is working as designed.

The listener that you have added in ProjectA is via the surefire plugin. The entries added via surefire plugin will not have any effect in downstream projects (for e.g., ProjectB).

If you need to have that, you would need to explicitly do one of the following in ProjectB

- Use `<listeners>` tag (or)
- Use ServiceLoader approach. Refer [here](https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#listeners-service-loader)

PS: Since your listener is an implementation of `org.testng.IAnnotationTransformer` you cannot use the `@Listeners` annotation to wire in this listener.